# Writing Shopify Bulk Mutation

Tags: graphql, shopify-api

I am new to GraphQL and new to Shopify. I am having a hard time understanding how to write Bulk operation mutation.

Here is my current challenge.

```
mutation {
  bulkOperationRunMutation(
    mutation: "mutation call($id: ID!, $input: [PublicationInput!]!) {publishableUnpublish(id: $id, input: $input) { userErrors { message field } } }",
    stagedUploadPath: "'. $uploadFilePath . '") {
    bulkOperation {
      id
      url
      status
    }
    userErrors {
      message
      field
    }
  }
}
```

I would appreciate if you can help answering the following :

1. What does the keyword `call` refers to? Is that a GraphQL keyword, or is it an `invention` by Shopify.
2. How do the argument to call [ in this case `$id: ID!, $input: PublicationInput!` , relate to argument to actual mutation , in this case id: `$id, input: $input`

I believe part of the problem is that there are two levels of mutation , on for BulK Operation , and then one for the actual operation , in the case `publishableUnpublish`.

Hit the following resources with no luck

https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#mutations

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2024-01/mutations/publishableUnpublish